# hide column based on font color in a table vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have some data in sheet1 as a table (named Table1), and I am changing the font color for some headers based on name and I want to only hide the header if its font color is black so keep orange and white un-hide. When I open the original worksheet, column headers has font color of white.

Right now when I run my codes, there are no error, but I only see columns with headers of orange font color which is not correct. For some reason when I convert my data into range, it works but I don't want to use `unlist` and re-create a table for the data.

```
Sub Data_Formatting()
   Dim i, j, k As Long      
Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Interior.Color = RGB(79, 129, 189)
 Last = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        If (Cells(1, i).Value) = "System" Then
         Cells(1, i).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End If
    Next i   
    For j = Last To 1 Step -1
        If (Cells(1, j).Value) = "AOB" Then
            Cells(1, j).Font.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
        End If
    Next j    
Range("A:D").Columns.AutoFit
    Dim l As Long
    Dim lColumn As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    'Last column
    lColumn = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For l = 1 To lColumn
        If Cells(1, l).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
            Cells(1, l).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else
            Cells(1, l).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to loop once here and do all of your logic in that one loop. The way you are doing it now is looping three times over the same set of columns just to perform slightly different actions.

```
Sub Data_Formatting()
    Dim i as Long    

    'set the background to blue
    Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Interior.Color = RGB(79, 129, 189)

    'Find last cell
    Last = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'autofit before hiding
    Range("A:D").Columns.AutoFit

    'loop once
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1       
        If (Cells(1, i).Value) = "System" Then
            Cells(1, i).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'black
            Columns(i).Hidden = True
        ElseIf Cells(1, j).Value = "AOB" Then
            Cells(1, j).Font.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0) 'orange
            Columns(i).Hidden = False
        End If
    Next i  
End Sub
```

With this change we don't have to bother detecting the cell color since you are setting that based on the value in the same loop. Test the value, set the color, and hide it all in one shot.